# Allow empty index of array in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Trying to insert data even if any index of array in foreach loop is empty. trying the following script its giving `Undefined index:` error in case of empty index.

```
$data = array();
if(count($_POST['data']) > 0 && !empty ($_POST['data'])){  
    foreach($_POST['data'] as $key => $array){
        $row = array();
        $row['team_id'] = intval($array['team_id']);
        $row['Note'] = strip_tags(trim(strval($array['Note'])));
        $row['result'] = strip_tags(trim(strval($array['result'])));
        $data[$key] = $row;
    }
        $sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO teams ('team_id','note','result') values (:team_id, :note, :result) ");

        foreach($data as $key => $array){
           $sql->execute(array(':team_id' => $array['team_id'], ':note' =>$array['Note'], ':result' => $array['result'], ));
    }
}
```

Comment: Check ``isset($_POST['data'])`` and `is_array($_POST['data'])` first.

Comment: @arkascha you mean instead of `&& !empty ($_POST['data'])` .

Comment: No before every index that is unsure you would place `isset($array['index'])` first

Comment: Provide the data you are getting from `$_POST['data']`. Try this `if(!empty ($_POST['data'])){`

Comment: That one does not make any sense anyway after the `count($_POST['data']) > 0`, does it? It can't be empty if its count is bigger than zero.

Comment: Your issue is that `$_POST['data']` is not set at all. You cannot test its count then, can you?

Comment: @arkascha OP is using more than one array in here

Comment: @DarkBee `$row['Note'] = strip_tags(trim(strval(isset($array['Note']))));` this its inserting 1 for every non empty index.

Comment: `$row['Note'] = isset($row['Note']) ? strip_tags(trim(strval($row['Note']))) : '';` ([tenary operator](https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent isset when set in variable

```
$row['team_id'] = isset($array['team_id']) ? intval($array['team_id']) : null;
$row['Note'] = isset($array['Note']) ? strip_tags(trim(strval($array['Note']))) : null;
$row['result'] = isset($array['result']) ? strip_tags(trim(strval($array['result']))) : null;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$data = array();
foreach ($_POST['data'] as $key => $array) {
    $data[$key]['team_id'] = isset($array['team_id']) ? intval($array['team_id']) : null;
    $data[$key]['Note'] = isset($array['Note']) ? strip_tags(trim(strval($array['Note']))) : null;
    $data[$key]['result'] = isset($array['result']) ? strip_tags(trim(strval($array['result']))) : null;

}

?>
```